# multimap of map data structure

Tags: c++, performance

I am parsing one file which has almost 1 billion(or may be trillion) records. I m using

```
 struct ltstr
 {
    bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
    {
        return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
    }
 };

 multimap<char*, map<char*, char*, ltsr>,ltstr > m;
```

Is this efficient way to use above data structure in C++?

Regards

Comment: `efficient ` when compared to? And efficient by memory or speed?

Comment: The unordered versions *should* be faster but require more memory. You should try both and decide from first hand experimentation

Comment: You don't tell us nearly enough about your data for us to tell. However, adding a billion entries to the multimap will likely use 10's of GBs of memory, maybe more. Is that ok for your system?

Comment: @Karthik T I need efficient in both way memory and speed.

Comment: Note these definitions use *pointer values* as keys, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: To be more specific than n.m., map with `char *` keys orders the items by _memory location of the strings_, not their content. You need either objects with defined `operator<` doing string comparison or pass extra template to the maps specifying correct string comparison.

Comment: If you go the custom comparison function route, you should at least make the key `char const *`, because the keys shall be immutable (if you modified content of the key, the map would not know and it's internal constraints would be broken).

Comment: @JanHudec I have modified my question by including comparator function. But my question "is it efficient way to do it?"

Comment: Efficient way to use this structure for storing trillions of records and priting them on a file.

Comment: @user15662: You don't load data to memory for sake of having them there. You load data to memory to do some processing on them. What is that processing?

Comment: Processing is some calculation on each value using another class which cannot be avoided.

Comment: @user15662: If the processing is calculation done on each value independently, than read the values one at a time, process each and discard it immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Billions, let alone trillions of records won't fit in operating memory of today's computer. Remember, billion records will consume 32 GB for the overhead of the map alone, further 16 GB for the pointers to the keys and values and obviously *n* more GB where *n* is average length of keys and values for the actual data (assuming 64-bit system; in 32-bit system it's only half, but it won't fit in the 3 GB address space limit). There are only few large servers in the world that have such amount of memory.

The only option for working with such huge amount of data is to process them in small batches. If the processing can be done on each element separately, just load one element at a time, process it and discard it. No matter what the size of the data, streaming processing is *always* faster, because it only requires fixed amount of memory and thus can efficiently take advantage of CPU caches.

If it can't be processed like that, because specific order is needed or you need to look up entries or something, you'll need to prepare the data to appropriate external (on-disk) structure. I.e. sort them with external merge sort (writing the partitions to temporary files), index them with B-tree or hash or such. It's a *lot* of work. But fortunately there are several libraries that implement these algorithms. I would suggest either:

- A [*DMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dbm), external hashing library, like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/), [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/berkeley-db/index.html) or ndbm. These provide just external analog of map, simplest, but the API is C-based.
- The [stxxl](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/) provides external variants of several external containers and algoritms that work on them. Big advantage is that the API is the same as standard library collections.
- For more complex data operation, just go for [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/). It's just as fast and more complex data processing is simply easier to express in SQL.